# How to sum numbers in a function's parameter and decrement second parameter until 0

Tags: php, function

I am new to php and I try to write a function that will return the sum  of two numbers written in parameters. And every time it does the sum I want to decrement the second parameter until 0.

for example : `sum(5,3)` - it will return `11` (because `5+3+2+1=11`)

How can I proceed?

This is my attempt so far:

```
<?php 
function customSum($a, $b) {
  if ($b == 0) { return $a; }

  $sum=0;
  for($x = $b; $x>0; $x--) {
    $sum = $x + $sum;
  }
  return $sum + $a;
}

echo customSum(5, 3); 
?>
```

Comment: Proceed by a) writing down your algorithm separately, in words (i.e. the process you want the function to go through in order to get the result), so anyone (including a human) could follow those instructions and use it to get the result. Then b) work out, line by line, how to translate that into PHP, by researching the basic things like mathmatical operators (e.g. `+ `and `-`) and how to use them, and how to do certain things like create a function, accept inputs, and return output. Tackle it one small piece at a time. Start without any function at all, for instance, just a basic program

Comment: i edited my question and added what i tried

Comment: <?php function customSum($a,$b){if($b==0){return $a;}$sum=0;for($x=$b;$x>0;$x--){$sum=$x+$sum;}return $sum+$a;}echo customSum(5,3); ?>

Comment: Ok great. So...tell me about the function. Does it work? Is there a specific problem with it? Explain what your difficult is, exactly.

Comment: P.S. It looks to me like it probably works (demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ddd9ff633596d70b1b96b7c54cd22210bfa0f209). If you still have any kind of issue, then please describe it in more detail. If you're happy with it, then great - well done, you wrote a useful function, it's satisfying when it works! Good luck with your future in programming.

Comment: Do **not** vandalise your own posts! Once posted, they 'belong' to the community.

Comment: It is good practice here to write an update below your original code and not to change the original question. That way everyone can see what brought you from question to answer. Other way round everybody has to guess .. :-)